# Sending a packets hex as packet

Tags: c, packet

Say I have a pcap from tcpdump with a handful of packets. I sort through and find one I need to send somewhere else, so I copy it’s hex. I have tried googling how to send the hex as a packet and have it come across as a properly setup packet, not just a raw hex. I would prefer this be done with C, but if another language would be better I’m all ears. I just haven’t been able to figure this out, and google hasn’t helped me much lol. Here is a packet for example.

52 54 00 7E 42 A5 52 54 00 A6 11 53 08 00 45 00 00 4A 4A 48 00 00 3F 11 F9 D7 C0 A8 38 0B C2 BE 7C 11 E7 3E 00 35 00 36 37 CB E4 A3 00 10 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 03 6E 73 32 0A 68 69 67 68 73 65 63 75 72 65 02 72 75 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 29 10 00 00 00 80 00 00 00

Any help?
Much thanks :)

Comment: What kind of packet do you want it to be sent as? Do you know the source/destination IP/port? Assuming ethernet as L2 protocol?

Comment: You need raw sockets. Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Ross, this particular packet I am unsure what it is as it was one randomly generated online. The ones I actually plan to use come in both udp and tcp flavors. The source and destination port and ip  will need to be made on the fly to be able to send to various destinations. 

And Semion I use Centos 7. If there’s a way to convert the hex to a list of data’s to set in a raw socket in the normal setup of headers and such, I’m extremely interested in learning. Thank you two!